# Show Current Month In Spinner

Tags: android

I have a spinner called month_spineer and used to show all the months in a year. I want to know, can I show the current month instead of the first value in spinner (For example, if its March, then it will show March instead of January when the activity start)?

Spinner xml :

```
<Spinner
                android:id="@+id/month_spinner"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="22dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
                android:entries="@array/month"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/et_year"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
```

Value For spinner

```
<string-array name="month">
    <item>January</item>
    <item>February</item>
    <item>March</item>
    <item>April</item>
    <item>May</item>
    <item>June</item>
    <item>July</item>
    <item>August</item>
    <item>September</item>
    <item>October</item>
    <item>November</item>
    <item>December</item>
</string-array>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the item index of the spinner programmatically by using below code

```
month_spinner.setSelection(indexofmonth);
```

In your activity get current month and set it as index to your spinner.

```
int indexofmonth = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH)
```